# why use redux with firebase?

Tags: firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, state

I'm asking for better understanding.
I am now using firebase and firestore as backend for a project. I know it is highly recommended to use a state management library such as redux or mobx as the single source of truth for application state. However, firestore is realtime database, what are the reasons then, to store the **real time data** from firestore in a state store prior to using in in the application ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what is the backend you use. You don't have to use redux and you shouldn't use it unless you need it and that depends on the application size and architecture. Ask yourself those questions:

- Will you be able to lift the state up to a shared parent component
  between the children that needs the same slice of state !? If yes,
  you don't need redux.
- Will you have to pass the state many levels down the component tree
  until it becomes annoying because a deeply nested component needs it
  !? If yes, you may need redux.

From redux website:

> In general, use Redux when you have reasonable amounts of data
>   changing over time, you need a single source of truth, and you find
>   that approaches like keeping everything in a top-level React
>   component's state are no longer sufficient.

You can read more about it here: [When should you use redux?](https://redux.js.org/faq/general/#when-should-i-use-redux)

Answer (score 0):

By emphasizing the **real-time data** from Firestore, I presume that you are using listeners to ensure that your data is fresh.

The article, [When should I use Redux?](https://redux.js.org/faq/general/#when-should-i-use-redux), is a great starting point for deciding whether Redux state is a good option for caching server-side data from Firestore.

However, even in cases where it might make sense to use Redux for server-side state, there are alternatives that you might want to consider.

The combination of Firebase with Redux has some pain points. Compared to other frameworks, it requires more effort to implement new features, even when streamlined with Redux-Toolkit. Furthermore, the typical design pattern involves calling `useEffect` to fetch data when a component mounts and storing that data in Redux state when appropriate. If you are using a listener, you would unsubscribe via `useEffect` when the component unmounts. This pattern runs afoul of the React roadmap. Future releases of React will, under certain circumstances, unmount and remount components in quick succession. This impending design change will cause lots of unnecessary data fetching at great expense for components that load data from inside the useEffect hook.

For more details see [What is Concurrent React?](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#what-is-concurrent-react)

I considered switching from Redux to React-Query (now renamed TanStack Query). But it’s not a great fit because TanStack Query’s sweet spot is pulling data from the server, not receiving data pushed from the server as Firestore does when using listeners. In the end, I decided to build a state management library from the ground-up tailored to Firebase’s unique features.

If you are not using listeners, then TanStack Query might be a good option for you to manage server-side state as an alternative to Redux.  But if you are using listeners, you might want to check out [@gmcfall/react-firebase-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gmcfall/react-firebase-state)